# What is 0 $\otimes$ M?

Tags: tensor-products

(I know the answer is 0 but I want an explanantion)

When we construct a A $\otimes$ B, we first make a free R module with basis from A x B, and then quotient is by relations like : (x+x',y)- (x,y) - (x',y) and a(x,y) - (ax,y) (same thing in the other coordinate). Now if choose only single module say M (and write is as 0 $\times$ M), then 0 $\otimes$ M is $A^M$ modulo the above relation. Now I don't see how the above relation generate $A^M$ because by intution I know the answer is 0

Comment: now I see why the above relation generate $A^M$, its because (x, y + y')- (x,y) -(x,y') is just (-x',0) and hence generate $A^M$ (since I didn't explicit write this express above, I missed this trick).

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$0\otimes m = 0\cdot0_R\otimes m = 0\otimes 0_R\cdot m = 0\otimes0$$
which is obviously the neutral element for the sum in $0\otimes M$.

Comment: yes I know this, but I was curious to know what if I tried to do it from scratch, like the one I outlined in the questions detail (it borrowed from Atiyah Macdonald chapter 2)

Comment: @BlueApple This answer *is* from scratch. In a bit more detail: The key observation is $$0\otimes b=(0\cdot 0)\otimes b=0\cdot (0\otimes b)=0\otimes (0\cdot b)=0\otimes 0.$$ Meanwhile, we clearly have $r(0\otimes 0)=(0\otimes 0)$, and $0\otimes 0+0\otimes 0=0\otimes 0$. So every linear combination of basic tensors (= every element of $0\otimes B$) is equal to $0\otimes 0$, hence $0\otimes B$ has a single element (and hence is the trivial $R$-module).

Comment: @NoahSchweber actually by scratch I didn't mean this, nonetheless I resolved the issue (it was silly overlooking of facts), if you are interested in what I mean, pls read the comment under the question.